# http GET from node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, callback, get

I'm fumbling my way through node.js with massive help from people on here and I'm struggling getting the body of a GET request into a variable.

Here's the code so far:

```
var speechOutput;

var myCallback = function(data) {
  console.log('got data: '+data);
  speechOutput = data;
};


var usingItNow = function(callback) {
  var http = require('http');    
  var url = 'http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN';

    var req = http.get(url, (res) => {
        var body = "";

        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on("end", () => {
            var result = JSON.parse(body);

            callback(result);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e){
      console.log("Got an error: ", e);
    });
};

usingItNow(myCallback);
```

I'm using examples from other posts to try and get the body of the GET request into the speechOutput variable but it is coming out as undefined.

Ultimately I want the RestResponse.result.name in speechOutput, but I thought I would take this one step at a time.  Can anyone offer any pointers?

Further to this, I have tried the following, which still came back undefined - maybe there is a bigger issue with the code? It doesn't even seem to be getting to the parse.

```
res.on("end", () => {
           // var result = JSON.parse(body);        
            callback('result');
        });
```

putting the line `callback('result');` before the line `var req = http.get(url, (res) => {` returns 'result' but anything else is either undefined or causes an error.

Comment: I think you are confusing the (non-existent) body of the GET request with the body of the response.

Comment: You've established that the `result` variable holds the value `undefined` … but you haven't dug back to find out why. Look at the value of `body`.

Comment: When I run that code, the output I get is `got data: [object Object]`. There's no error. There's no sign of `undefined`. I can't reproduce the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Roy T. [Fielding](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/messages/9962):

> Server semantics for GET, however, are restricted such that a body,
>   if any, has no semantic meaning to the request. The requirements
>   on parsing are separate from the requirements on method semantics.

Don't use get request to send body parameters. Use post requests. If you want to send data within a get request, add them to the query string.

Read this for more info about bodies in get requests:
[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body?rq=1)

Update:

Try to log errors in the response, add this before you set up the listeners:

```js
  var body = "";
  const { statusCode } = res;
  const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

  let error;
  if (statusCode !== 200) {
    error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                      `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
  } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
    error = new Error('Invalid content-type.\n' +
                      `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
  }
  if (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    // consume response data to free up memory
    res.resume();
    return;
  }
 res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
    });
```

Comment: I'm not wanting to pass a body, I just want to call the URL and receive a body.